# Where do we register a driver in a PySpark program?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

To retrive data from an RDBMS database (postgres), while working with scala and spark, I wrote the below code:

```
class GpMeta(spark:SparkSession, source_system_name:String, conParams:ParametersDto) {
    import spark.implicits._
    try {
        Class.forName(conParams.getGpDriverClass()).newInstance()
    }
    catch {
        case cnf: ClassNotFoundException =>
            println("No class def found for Hive Metastore. Exiting the application....")
            System.exit(1)
        case e: Exception =>
            println("No class def found for Hive Metastore. Exiting the application....")
            System.exit(1)
    }
    def getControlTableData(): Unit = {
        val cdf = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", conParams.getGpConUrl()).option("dbtable", s"(select target_table, id from schema.table where source_system_name='${source_system_name}' and transfer_status is null and tenant_code='HDFS') as controlTableDF").option("user", conParams.getGpUserName()).option("password", conParams.getGpPwd()).load()
        cdf.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)
        cdf.createOrReplaceTempView("cdfTemp")
}
```

This works perfectly. I am trying to replicate the same in Python (learning Python now) but don't understand how to create a driver instance inside a .py file. I have written this piece of codee so far:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import psycopg2 

def get_interface_log_ids(spark):
    idf = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","").option("user","user").option("password","pwd")option("dbtable",f"select target_table from schema.table where source_system_name='SSS' and transfer_status is null and tenant_code='HDFS' order by interface_log_id desc) as controlTableDF").load()
    idf.persist("MEMORY_ONLY")
    return idf


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("DummyAP")
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
    get_interface_log_ids(spark)
```

If I try to give the driver instance in the code as below: `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")`
I see an error message: Unresolved reference 'Class'. Is this the right way to register a driver in Python code ?
Also I see this [link](https://stackabuse.com/working-with-postgresql-in-python/) for postgres python jdbc connection. If I am supposed to use the code in that link, where do I specify to Python and Spark that I am using Postgres driver ?

Could anyone let me know how can I correct my mistake ?

Comment: there is no `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` in python. Can you try to remove this ?

Comment: Ok. So in such case, where do I register the drivere ? I know that we can pass --drivere-class-path in spar-submit command but in the code, how I do I tell Python/Spark that I am using a specific driver if there is no Class.forName in Python ?

Answer (score 1):

Give the 'spark conf' a property named "spark.jars" and a value of the jar's absolute path, an example as follows:

```
    SparkConf() 
       .setAppName("DummyAP")
       .set("spark.jars", "/where/your/driver/located/postgresql-*-*-*.jdbc4.jar")
```

Also; you may check the official docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), which may be helpful.

Comment: Tried that `sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("DummyAP").set("spark.jars","/home/fdlhdpetl/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar")` but still see 
`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`

Answer (score 1):

Update my previous answer. 
There are two properties needed which is :

"spark.jars" and "spark.driver.extraClassPath" ,

So; the code should be looked like this :

```
conf = SparkConf()
    .setAppName("PostGreSQL")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.jars", "path/to/jar/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar")
    .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "path/to/jar/lib/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar") 

spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(conf=conf)
    .getOrCreate()

jdbcDF = spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://*.*.*.*/")
    .option("dbtable", '"Test"."Table1"')
    .option("user", "postgres")
    .option("password", "******")
    .load()
jdbcDF.registerTempTable("PostGreSQL")
spark.sql(""" SELECT * FROM PostgreSQL """).show()
```